# The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

What is the problem with this code.

It is giving this error `The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.` when some exception is coming in the procedure. How can I solve it?

```
    BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    DECLARE  
         @Id bigint 
        ,@Month nvarchar(100) 
        ,@Year nvarchar(100) 
        ,@CountryofExport nvarchar(100)
        ,@CountryofOrigin nvarchar(100) 
        ,@HSCode nvarchar(100)
        ,@Unit nvarchar(100)
        ,@Quantity nvarchar(100)
        ,@CustomValue nvarchar(255)
        ,@Type nvarchar(100)
        ,@TypeBit bit
        ,@CountryofExportID int
        ,@CountryofOriginID int
        ,@MeasurementId int
        ,@Remarks nvarchar(500)
        ,@CommodityId int
        ,@SDate nvarchar(100)
        ,@SameRec int
        ,@counts int


    DECLARE @Cursor_TradeFlow CURSOR
    SET @Cursor_TradeFlow = CURSOR FOR

    SELECT [Id],[Months],[Years],[CountryofExport],[CountryofOrigin],[HSCode],[Quantity],[Unit],[CustomValue],[Type] FROM [Temp_Trading]    

    OPEN @Cursor_TradeFlow
    FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor_TradeFlow INTO @Id, @Month, @Year, @CountryofExport, @CountryofOrigin, @HSCode,@Quantity, @Unit, @CustomValue, @Type

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN
    Set @Remarks='';




   Declare @EICountry varchar(100),
   @Checkbit bit,
    @CheckYearIsNumeric bit,
    @CheckMonthIsNumeric bit


      BEGIN TRY        

         SET @CheckMonthIsNumeric= convert(INT, @Month);

      END TRY 

      BEGIN CATCH
    begin

             set @Checkbit=1;
         set @Remarks = @Remarks + 'Invalid Month'
         set @CheckMonthIsNumeric=1 
         end
      END CATCH



      BEGIN TRY

          set @CheckYearIsNumeric=  convert(INT, @Year);

      END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH


        SET @CheckYearIsNumeric= 1;
        set @Checkbit=1;
        set @Remarks = @Remarks + 'Invalid Year'

      END CATCH      


    Set @SameRec = (Select COUNT(*) From TradeFlow Where int_Month = @CheckMonthIsNumeric and int_Year = @CheckYearIsNumeric
                  and int_OriginLocationId = @CountryofExportID and int_DestinationLocationId = @CountryofOriginID and int_CommodityId = @CommodityId
                  and int_MeasurementId = @MeasurementId)   


    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
         ROLLBACK
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor_TradeFlow INTO @Id, @Month, @Year, @CountryofExport, @CountryofOrigin, @HSCode,@Quantity, @Unit, @CustomValue, @Type

    END
    CLOSE @Cursor_TradeFlow
    DEALLOCATE @Cursor_TradeFlow
    COMMIT
END
```

Comment: Please show all relevant code. Your code doesn't contain `COMMIT TRANSACTION`

Comment: You're already using Try/Catch in several places, is there any reason you're not using it instead of @@Error? For example a global try/catch around your entire loop (instead of the current @@error check) would be a simplistic solution to your issue - any unexpected issue would roll the whole thing back.

Comment: Why are you using a cursor at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having:

```
IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
     ROLLBACK
END
```

inside a cursor loop is a bad sign - you rollback the transaction, and then continue into the next iteration. When the loop finally finishes, you attempt to commit and - Oops - there's no open transaction any longer, and every operation after the rollback has been left in place.

You might want to exit the loop after the rollback using a `GOTO`, or deal with the errors in a different way. It's too hard to tell what the best strategy might be.

Answer (score 0):

You could use named transactions:

> -- big transaction in the beginning
>     BEGIN TRANSACTION BIG_TRANSACTION
>
> ```
> -- your code here
>
> -- a transaction for each fetched item 
> BEGIN TRANSACTION FETCH_TRANSACTION
> -- your code here
> if OK
>     COMMIT TRANSACTION FETCH_TRANSACTION
> else
>     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION FETCH_TRANSACTION
> ```
>
> COMMIT/ROLLBACK TRANSACTION BIG_TRANSACTION